# Is the phrase «as general an answer as possible» correct?

Tags: comparative-constructions, as, predeterminers

Is it correct to say:

> *It would be nice to have as general an answer as possible*.

I'm not sure... I think I've read similar sentences, if I'm not mistaken.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: It sounds good to this native speaker.

Comment: "As general of an answer as possible" sounds better to me.

Comment: I think it is OK, but *have* may not be the best verb. If this is about an answer you expect in reply to a question, I would go with "It would be nice *to receive/get* as general an answer as possible.

Comment: It is a very common construction. "Go and get *as big a bowl as you can find* and make a giant salad for the party."  It puts emphasis on the adjective.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, that's fine.

> **as general** an answer **as possible**

means the same thing as

> an answer *that is* **as general as possible**

In other words, an answer that cannot be any more general.  It has already been made general to the extent that is possible.

Grammatically, the adjective phrase *as general* appears in Predeterminer position, which has that name because it comes before the Determiner *an*.  It licenses the post-head Complement *as possible*.

This construction is covered in Michael Swan's *Practical English Usage* (3rd edition) in section 14.  For a more technical reference, see *The Cambridge Grammar of the English Language*, page 435.

Comment: Thanks for the answer and the references therein. (by the way it's ok this use of 'therein'? =D )